# Evaluating an item of a certain index in a list within a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm making a program that lists students, their degree and courses, among other things, for browsing. I haven't been able to wrap my head around what would be the way to iterate through an item of a specific index in a list of lists. The list of lists contains student information like this:

```
[['2004S','3001','Johnson John','149','HETY2','STIL'],
['2004S','3002','Steveson Steve','224','HETY2','SEIT'],
['2004S','3003','Jackson Jack','270','HETY2','SEIT'],
...
['2007S','3124','Ericsson Eric','286','HETY2','SPII']]
```

What I want to do is evaluate the first item of each list with an input I get from an Entry widget. The first item is the year a student has started their studies. So in the Entry field I ask what year's students the user wants to browse. If the value evaluates true, I append the whole list into another list, all of which I display on the screen later. Something like this:

```
class Model():
...
    def searched_year(self, year):
        for object in self.student.parse_student_info():
            for elem in range(len(self.student.parse_student_info())):
                matching = [object for elem in object if str(year) in elem]
        return matching
```

The `parse_student_info()` method is called from the `Student` class with the 'student' object and it returns the whole list of lists, as seen above. The argument 'year' is the `StringVar` I get from the Entry widget. This code returns an empty list each time (and does not yet limit the search to an index). What is the best way of doing this?

EDIT:

More essential code:

```
class Student():
...
    def parse_student_info(self):
        with open('opiskelijat.txt', 'r') as src:
            separ = src.readlines()
            studentinfo = [elem.strip().split(';') for elem in separ]
            return studentinfo
```

This is the `parse_student_info()` method in the `Student` class. It returns the list of lists you see above. It works as intended. Below is the `search_year()` method that calls the method in question.

```
UIController():
...
    def search_year(self, year):
        mode = Model()
        return mode.searched_year(year)
```

The `UIController` class controls all the different `Frame` classes that contain the buttons and other widgets, and it also interacts with the `Model` class that handles the information from `Student`, `Course` and `Degree` classes.

So far the method still prints an empty list.

Comment: Just as a design tip, "The parse_student_info()-method is called from the Student class with the 'student' object and it returns the whole list of lists, as seen above." This type of function should not belong to a `Student` object. The `Students` shouldn't have to be aware of anything but themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to take the output of parse_student_info() and return a list of lists where the first element of each sub-list matches a given value, yes? Try this:

```
def searched_year(self, year):
    return [rec for rec in self.student.parse_student_info() if rec[0] is year]
```

Comment: Your way of doing it looks that it should work, but when I tried it the program still printed an empty list. I don't know what is causing this to happen. I edited my post to have some more information if it's useful.

Comment: That means that the problem is with either parsing the file or getting the year input. Your `parse_student_info()` above will work as long as each line in the file looks like this: `2004S;3001;Johnson John;149;HETY2;STIL`. That leaves search_year(), about which I can tell little. Given that the years in the sample data all have `S` on the end, is it possible that you're getting input that's just a number with no S?

Comment: Yup, I solved it now. Thanks for the aid! I had it the way you described in the original comment but I changed the `StringVar` to an `IntVar` and turned the last `if` clause to contain `in` instead of `is`. Like this: `return [sublist for sublist in self.student.parse_student_info() if str(year) in sublist[0]]`